# What're config steps for a low load/RAM CentOS-Apache-MySQL-PHP setup?

Tags: centos, configuration, lamp, memory

Also, what the minimal memory required to run CentOS, Apache, MySQL, PHP together?

If it matters, the current target is a VPS provider named SliceHost on a 256Mb RAM slice/VM.

Here's my notes so far:

**CentOS-5.x**

  Use 32-bit instead of 64-bit if possible.

  Disable all unnecessary services.

**Apache 2.X**

  Cache page loads using: mod_cache, XCache, or .

  Disable all unnecessary modules.

  Review Lighttpd and nginx to see if they meet your requirements

**MySQL**

  MySQLTuner

  SQLite (runs under PHP process) -- In my case I need MySQL for Drupal, but the next release is suppose to support SQLite.

**PHP**

  PHP-FPM with daily cron to restart.

**Drupal**

  Haven't found anything, except a caching module, which appears to be no better than using Apache. Since Apache's more secure I'd rather use that unless I'm miss understanding something.

***DO NOT***

  Install: Web-based_webadmin_Tools(phpMyAdmin,webmin,etc.), FTP, Mail-Server, Mail/Spam_Server, Anti-Virus, VNC

**_______**

**Any suggestions? If my list is missing something, or wrong -- let me know. Also, is it possible to even run LAMP on 256 on a low load site? Thanks!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of that would run just fine, except for MySQL.
I recommend you get another MySQL host, as MySQL takes up to 220MB of RAM om my VPS while idle, that's why I switched to SQLite.

Comment: Did you see my note about SQLite because it'll run under PHP process, but in my case I need MySQL for Drupal-6.X (based on my understanding), but the next release is suppose to support SQLite. I open to not running MySQL, if I'm able to get Drupal up without it. Thanks!

Comment: MySQL uses as much RAM as you allow it to use. I run a few LAMP sites on a VPS with 256MB RAM without any problems at all.